# Solve improper double integral using integrate and uniroot functions

Tags: r, numerical-integration, uniroot

We have a function. t ~ Weibull(alpha, lambda) and c ~ Exponential(beta):

[image]

Given `p = 0.10`, `alpha = 1`, `lambda = 4`. Find the value of `beta`.

We want to integrate this function for `t` then to `c`. Then find the value of `beta` where integral equals to `p` using `uniroot` function.

See the code below:

```
alpha = 1
lambda = 4
p = 0.10
func1 <- function(t, c, beta) {alpha * lambda * exp(-lambda * t^ alpha)*
                           beta * exp(- beta * c) }
func2 <- function(c, beta){integrate(func1, lower = c, upper = Inf, c=c, 
beta=beta)}
func3 <- function(beta){integrate(func2, lower = 0, upper = Inf, beta = 
beta)$value - cen.p}
uniroot(func3 ,lower = 0.001, upper = 10, extendInt = "yes")$root
```

However it throws the error:

> Error in integrate(func1, lower = c, upper = Inf, c = c, beta = beta)
> :  length(lower) == 1 not TRUE

Answer should be  `0.444`

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks Rogue. Now, I add my code in R-studio. This code report that:  length(lower) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. I want to solve attached function to get "B" or beta of exponential distribution. we set alpha=1, lambda=4, p=0.10, beta=? . I write code in rstudio but it's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected typos (substituted `cen.p` to `p`) and vectorized function arguments for `func2` and `func3`, since the `integrate` function returns one value (scalar). However as a first argument `integrate` should accept vector of numeric values, not a scalar.

```
alpha <- 1
lambda <- 4
p <- 0.10
func1 <- function(t, c, beta)
  alpha * lambda * t^(alpha - 1) * exp(-lambda * t^alpha) * beta * exp(-beta * c)

func2 <- function(c, beta)
  integrate(func1, lower = c, upper = Inf, c = c, beta = beta)$value)

func3 <- function(beta)
  integrate(Vectorize(func2), lower = 0, upper = Inf, beta = beta)$value - p

uniroot(Vectorize(func3), lower = 0.001, upper = 10, extendInt = "yes")$root
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.4444242.
```

Comment: thanks a lot. One note: This code for a=0.25 report error. why?                                           
Error in integrate(Vectorize(func2), lower = 0, upper = Inf, beta = beta) : 
the integral is probably divergent

Comment: You ommited t^(alpha - 1) multiplier from function, code corrected. Please check.